# Possible to pass List<S3Target> as input to Cloud Formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I have an `AWS::Glue::Crawler` resource defined in cloudformation like so:

```
# ...

Parameters:
  pS3Targets:
    Type: List<AWS::Glue::Crawler::S3Target>  # <-- I want this. This does not appear to be supported

Resources:

# ...

  rCrawler:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties:
      Name: "my_crawler"
      DatabaseName: "my_db"
      Role: !GetAtt myRole.Arn
      Schedule:
        ScheduleExpression: !Ref pCrawlerSchedule
      Targets:
        # TODO: parameterize the List of S3Targets
        S3Targets:
          - Path: !Sub "s3://my-bucket/table1/"
          - Path: !Sub "s3://my-bucket/table2/"
          - Path: !Sub "s3://my-bucket/table3/"
          - Path: !Sub "s3://my-bucket/tableN/"
```

I want to be able to pass a variable number of S3 paths ([S3Target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-crawler-s3target.html) type) to the cloudformation template. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only [AWS-Specific Parameter Types are listed here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types)

Comment: You can use [macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html#template-macros-lambda-interface) to transform your template. You might also be able to use a combo of `Fn::If` and `Fn::Select` with a limited number of targets. Not sure how that would work with "empty targets" though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not perfect, but this is the only way I found that is close to your goal:

```
Parameters:
  pS3Targets:
    Type: String
    Default: "s3://path1,s3://path2"

Resources:
  rCrawler:
    ...
    Targets:
      S3Targets:
        - Path: !Select [0, !Split [",", !Ref pS3Targets]]
        - Path: !Select [1, !Split [",", !Ref pS3Targets]]
```